# Convert IR Pattern Android from ~4.4.2 to 4.4.3

Tags: android, converters, infrared

Is there a way to convert a IR pattern from a Android ~4.4.2 to 4.4.3 compatible pattern.
Android ~4.4.2 is using a number of cycles and 4.4.3 is using the on and offtime in µs.

Here is a example how they look like

```
private static final int SAMPLE_FREQ = 38400;
private static final int[] IR_SIGNAL_PULSE_COUNT = {171,171,22,64,22,64,22,64,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,64,22,64,22,64,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,64,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,64,22,64,22,21,22,64,22,64,22,64,22,64,22,64,22,876};

private static final int[] IR_SIGNAL_TIME_LENGTH = {4499,4499,578,1683,578,1683,578,1683,578,552,578,552,578,552,578,552,578,552,578,1683,578,1683,578,1683,578,552,578,552,578,552,578,552,578,552,578,552,578,552,578,1683,578,552,578,552,578,552,578,552,578,552,578,1683,578,1683,578,552,578,1683,578,1683,578,1683,578,1683,578,1683,578,23047};
```

Theoretically this should work but it don't

```
private int[] toCompIR(IrDataCompat data){
    int inUs = 1000000/data.getFrequency();
    int[] frame = data.getFrame();
    int[] arrayOfInt = new int[-1 + frame.length];
    for (int j = 1; j < frame.length; j++)
        arrayOfInt[(j - 1)] = frame[(j - 1)] * inUs;

    return arrayOfInt;
}
```

Comment: I know this is really old, but have a look at this:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/28934938/1042362

Answer (score 0):

You might run into a rounding error.

Please try

> float inUs = 1000000.0f/data.getFrequency()